# delete user from table

Tags: mysql, database

I have this table where I want to delete user from. The users are in my database "login" where they have an id, username and password.

"Id" is the primary key, I want to delete the user where I click in my table

Hope you can help me out!

```
<?php


                    $account = '<font size="4">'.$account.'</font>';
                    $password1 = 'Password:';
                    $password1 = '<font size="4">'.$password1.'</font>';
                        //check db connection
                        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                        } 
                        // Take everything from table and fill in $result
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);

                        echo"<table border=4><tr><td>$account</td><td>$password1</td><td>Action</td></tr>";

                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            // Take all data
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                echo"<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td> edit | delete </td></tr>";

                            }
                        } else {
                            // nothing in DB is 0 results
                            echo "0 results";
                        }
                        echo"</table>";
                        $conn->close();




                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <td> edit | <a href='baseURL/deleteUser.php&id=$userId'> delete</a> </td></tr>";
```

create a page `deleteuser.php`, get the id via `$_GET['id']` and delete accordingly.

This is a very crude approach to delete users and the id goes via browser url. You can add forms here and delete text can be a submit button .. The id can be sent as hidden and obtained via `$_POST`

Comment: unfortunately my page get blank when I add 

<td> edit | <a href='baseURL/deleteUser.php&id=$userId>" delete"</a> </td></tr>";